# I am a bit hungry. Bit vs very

Tags: grammar

> I am very hungry.
>
> I am a bit hungry.

What is the opposite of "very"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, *a bit* works just fine. So does *a little*:

> I'm **a little** hungry.

Another way you could say it (with a single word) would be to use *somewhat*:

> I was ***very*** ashamed of my actions.
>   I was ***a bit*** ashamed of my actions.
>   I was ***somewhat*** ashamed of my actions.

Compare NOAD's defintions of the two words:

> **somewhat** (*adverb*)
>   to a moderate extent or by a moderate amount
>   **very** (*adverb*)
>   in a high degree

Comment: Also "slightly", "barely", although I agree that "a little" sits better with "hungry". "Quite" is interesting in that it's ambiguous but disambiguated by context, it can mean either "somewhat" or "very" or "completely".

Answer (score 1):

> I am **not very** hungry.

`very` and `bit` express varying degrees of hungriness, and I would certainly not call them opposites. `not very`, on the other hand, could be used to express any of these hungry degrees:

> I am **a bit** hungry.
>
> I am **moderately** hungry.
>
> I am **not** hungry **at all**.